# Gatling recorder with Google Auth

Tags: performance, gatling

I'm starting to learn Gatling and using Gatling Recorder.

In my SUT, login is done via Google Auth, but when I try to record steps with Gatling Recorder and Firefox with the proxy set, I receive the following message:

```
Your connection is not secure

The owner of accounts.google.com has configured their website improperly. 
To protect your information from being stolen, Firefox has not connected to this website.

This site uses HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) to specify that Firefox only connects to it securely. 
As a result, it is not possible to add an exception for this certificate.

accounts.google.com uses an invalid security certificate. 
The certificate is not trusted because it is self-signed. 
The certificate is only valid for Gatling Error code: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER
```

I've tried HTTPS Mode "Certificate Authority" with the certificate generated from Gatling and the message is:

```
Your connection is not secure

The owner of accounts.google.com has configured their website improperly. 
To protect your information from being stolen, Firefox has not connected to this website.

This site uses HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) to specify that Firefox only connects to it securely. 
As a result, it is not possible to add an exception for this certificate.

accounts.google.com uses an invalid security certificate. 
The certificate does not come from a trusted source. 
Error code: MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_V1_CERT_USED_AS_CA
```

I've tried using a manually self-signed certificate but again with no success.

Does someone have an idea how to use Gatling Recorder with Google Auth?

Comment: I realize not a proxy recorder solution, but you can use the [import HAR file](http://gatling.io/docs/2.0.0-RC2/http/recorder.html#har-files) option in gatling recorder to generate a simulation. Mozilla help shows [how to export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor#CopySave_All_As_HAR) it's own network recording as HAR file.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't something you can actually **record**, if your application uses Google credentials for authentication, most probably you need to implement [OAuth](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect) flow in your Gatling test i.e.

- Provide [OAuth credentials](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#getcredentials) as a part of your request
- Extract dynamic response parts like redirect URL or using Checks
- Once you get Access Token add the relevant [Header](http://gatling.io/docs/2.2.3/http/http_request.html#headers) to your request

See the following references:

- [OAuth in Gatling](https://andreypanasyuk.wordpress.com/2015/12/11/oauth-in-gatling/)
- [HTTP: support Google OAuth2](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/1976)
- [How to Run Performance Tests on OAuth Secured Apps with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-oauth-secured-apps-jmeter) (this one is about JMeter but you should be able to apply the same solutions)